# How to Query n months ago in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, query

I am trying to write a query which returns data from 3 months back and bases the current month from the system time. So if the query ran today, it would return May data. Something like:

```
List<testing> myList = [select id, name.....from .... where month__c = 3_MONTHS_AGO ...]
```

Is there a nice way of doing this in `Apex`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the month to use in your filter as follows:

```
Integer target = Date.today().addMonths(-3).month();
```

So your filter would be:

```
WHERE Month__c = :target
```

Or you could just inline it:

```
WHERE Month__c = :Date.today().addMonths(-3).month()
```

If you have a `Date` or `Datetime` field, you can use [Date Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm):

```
WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH (DateField__c) = :target
```

Comment: This is working well! Awesome. I used the CALENDER_MONTH way.

Comment: You could also use the SOQL Date Literals `Month__c = LAST_N_MONTHS:3 AND Month__c !=  LAST_N_MONTHS:2`. That's pretty clunky though...