# replacing LAST_MONTH

Tags: apex, soql, query, date, date-literals

I have some code that depends on `LAST_MONTH`. Something like:

```
select  .... date__c .. FROM myTable__c where date__c = LAST_MONTH
```

This code, as I understand, returns a result set constrained to

```
firstOfPastMonth <= date__c <= LastOfPastMonth
```

In order to make this query ready to run for any other month and not only for the last one, I tried to eliminate the use of `LAST_MONTH` by using variables like:

```
iniMonth = myToday.addMonths(-1).toStartOfMonth();  
endMonth = iniMonth.addDays(date.daysInMonth((integer) iniMonth.year(), (integer) iniMonth.month()));
```

where myToday represents a call to a date that belongs to the month just after the needed month. So I got:

```
select  .... date__c ...
FROM myTable__c
where date__c >= :iniMonth AND
  date__c < :endMonth
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might consider some other [`SOQL Date Literals`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) such as `LAST_N_MONTHS`.

> **Date Literal**
> `LAST_N_MONTHS:n`
>
> **Rage**
> For the number n provided, starts 00:00:00 of the last day of the previous month and continues for the past n months.

So this query filter will take everything before today until the beginning of the month *n* months ago. Because of that, you need to also exclude the range of all dates between the beginning of today and the end of that month, in order to get just that particular month.
For example, if you wanted to get six months ago instead of last month, you would use:

```
WHERE Date__c = LAST_N_MONTHS:6
AND Date__c < LAST_N_MONTHS:5
```

The advantage to using this approach is that it's more portable if you want to run the query somewhere you can't access Apex. For example, it will work just fine in Data Loader.

---

As for the logic you *have*, you can make it much more concise, and your initial code had two obvious problems, both of which you fixed in some manner before I could respond to your additional questions in the comments:

- You were missing your colon characters (`:`) before your merged values.
- You were including an extra day at the end of the range (since your filter was inclusive).

There are two ways to fix the second bullet point. You can use a non-inclusive filter (`<` instead of `<=`) for the end of your range, as you have done. I would say it's easier to understand if you use the actual dates for the month. Consider for example if you run the code for last month:

```
Integer n = 1;
Date monthStart = Date.today().addMonths(-n).toStartOfMonth();  
Date monthEnd = monthStart.addDays(Date.daysInMonth(monthStart.year(), monthStart.month()));
system.debug(monthStart);
system.debug(monthEnd);
```

The above script yields:

> [4]|DEBUG|2017-01-01 00:00:00
> [5]|DEBUG|2017-02-01 00:00:00

You can get the correct dates and use an inclusive range with something like:

```
Date monthStart = Date.today().addMonths(-n).toStartOfMonth();
Date monthEnd = monthStart.addMonths(1).addDays(-1);

... WHERE Date__c >= :monthStart AND Date__c < :monthEnd
```

Comment: It isn't documented anywhere that I can find, but using `N_MONTHS_AGO:n` does work for me (as well as `N_DAYS_AGO`, `N_WEEKS_AGO`, `N_QUARTERS_AGO`, etc...). These date literals accomplish exactly what the OP wants in a single expression...if you feel safe using a feature of dubious documentation.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You misunderstand me, the `LAST_N_MONTHS:n` date literal is documented (as you linked). I'm saying that instead of using `date  = LAST_N_MONTHS:6 AND date < LAST_N_MONTHS:5`, you can use `N_MONTHS_AGO:6` instead. The part I was referring to as being undocumented is the fact that `N_MONTHS_AGO:n` exists.

Comment: @DerekF I get it now. Woah. That's pretty cool! Might be worth a separate answer. :) Although I will probably stick to using documented functionality myself.

Comment: @DerekF I've submitted feedback on that document. We'll see if they update it.

Comment: but if  date__c < '2017-02-01 00:00:00'  then date__c can maximum get '2017-01-01 23:59:59'. Am I correct?

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga Yes the whole point is that your initial query used an inclusive filter (`<=`). I say in my post that you can either use an exclusive filter (`<`) or change the dates. As your post is written *now* your logic is correct. Perhaps you see now why significant edits can make it really difficult to post a sensible answer. It may be better in the future to try to leave what you had intact and post an **`EDIT`** section.

Comment: Thanks! Just to leave a reference to a similar problem:
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137731/how-to-query-n-months-ago-in-soql

Answer (score 4):

It isn't officially documented anywhere that I can find, but there are extra Date Literals that you can use of the form `N_<date scale>_AGO:n`, such as `N_DAYS_AGO`, `N_WEEKS_AGO`, `N_MONTHS_AGO`, `N_QUARTERS_AGO`, etc...

Of these, `N_MONTHS_AGO` is the one that you're looking for.

```
SELECT <some fields>
FROM myTable__c
WHERE date__c = N_MONTHS_AGO:6
```

This is equivalent to the more documented solution (using `LAST_N_MONTHS`) that Adrian uses.

If you happened to run the query from either solution today (2017-2-13, for records 6 months ago),the query will filter the results of your query to only include records where `Date__c` is between 2016-08-01 and 2016-08-31.

The only unfortunate bit with using date literals (both the documented and undocumented ones) is that you can't bind an apex variable to use for the date literal.

In other words, the following `WHERE` clause won't work

```
WHERE date__c = N_MONTHS_AGO::someApexIntegerVariable
```

If you want to use the same query, but with a variable integer `n` for the date literal, you'll need to use dynamic soql like so

```
Integer numMonthsAgo = 6;
database.query('SELECT Id FROM MyObject__c WHERE Date__c = N_MONTHS_AGO:' + numMonthsAgo);
```

Comment: `N_MONTHS_AGO ` relative date filter is documented in [Relative Date Values for Filter Criteria](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_dates.htm&type=0) and **IS NOT equivalent** of `LAST_N_MONTHS` - the difference is that `N_MONTHS_AGO `returns only the data for a specific month from N months ago while `LAST_N_MONTHS` is returning all months starting from N months back and up to last month (inclusive)

Comment: That documentation is close, but not a complete match (it appears to apply to  listviews only, not SOQL. The syntax is also slightly different). If a listview simply issues a SOQL query in the back-end, It might explain why we can use it in SOQL.

Comment: @Oleksiy regarding the difference between `N_MONTHS_AGO:6` and `LAST_N_MONTHS:6`, I do not claim that they are equivalent. Rather, my claim is that `WHERE Date__c = N_MONTHS_AGO:6` and `WHERE Date__c = LAST_N_MONTHS:6 AND Date__c < LAST_N_MONTHS:5` are equivalent.

Comment: Ohh, I see now... In this case it's preferable to use `N_MONTHS_AGO:6`.